# How to Create data frame schema from a header file

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have  2 data files:

1 file is header file and other is data file.
Header file is  having 2 columns (Id,Tags):header.txt

```
Id,Tags
```

Now I am trying to create a dataFrame Schema Out of  the header file:(I have to use this approach as in real time ,there are 1000 of columns in header.txt and data.txt. So,manually creating case class with 1000 column is not possible.

```
val  dataFile=sparkSession.read.format("text").load("data.txt")

val headerFile=sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("header.txt")

val fields= 
headerFile.flatMap(x=>x.split(",")).map(fieldName=>StructField(fieldName,StringType,true))

val schema=StructType(fields)
```

But above line is failing with **Cannot resolve overloaded method StructType**.

Can some one please help

Answer (score 0):

StructType needs an array of StructField and you are using fields variable which is an RDD[String] so **collect** the rdd to create StructType.

```
val fields= headerFile.flatMap(x=>x.split(","))
            .map(fieldName=>StructField(fieldName,StringType,true))

val schema=StructType(fields.collect)
```

Comment: Thank u so much. It will not impact performance correct in real production doing collect?  I did: val headerFile=sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("src/main/resources/header.txt").repartition(1).   Did a repartition(1)...will it be fine from performance standpoint?

Comment: How many headers do you expect? Collect is not good in performance but in your use case I think is a good option and don't impact.